# Can I get married at 16 without any job or income?

Tags: nikah, family

I'm currently just 16 years old and I'm interested in marrying but I'm not sure if this is right as I don't have a job yet and I'm still in school. I want to marry so as to prevent myself from zina as I feel I can't resist the temptations. My parents believe that I need a job or to finish studies etc to marry since the customs are like that these days. Can I get married without a job?

Comment: Do you live with your parents or own your own? Can you afford to rent your own place and two square meals a day? If not, I recommend first getting a job even if minimum wage and stick to it for 2-3 months. Save some money and then pop the question. Alternately, try to complete your degree, get a job and then marry. In the meantime analyze if you can marry the girl but ask permission from her parents to take her to your place only when you have saved enough money to support both of you.

Comment: Please make your question concise. Repetition and unnecessary details are distracting. Neither age nor wealth or income are a condition for the validity of marriage, although practically it would be difficult to find someone who would agree to such a marriage ... if you are somehow able to marry then you should go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider coming up to the point while adding all necessary information. We don't need to know about the girl's family more than whether or not they accept this marriage and our modern day issues such as the presence of zina is not something specific to you. ...

As for whether or not one is allowed to get married once one has reached maturity (especially for a male) the answer is yes.
As for being able to get married neither a special age nor wealth is required or even a condition for its validity.

But for a legal marriage there are three parties that must come to an agreement:
The groom, the bride and the bride's guardian.
And as @UmH already pointed at in the comment: You may hardly find parents who will accept marrying their daughter to a boy or young man who is not able to be in charge for his family.
And actually not being in charge for your wife and kids might be a legal reason to invalidate or end a marriage according to some scholars as Allah says:

> Men are in charge of women by [right of] what Allah has given one over the other and what they spend [for maintenance] from their wealth. So righteous women are devoutly obedient, guarding in [the husband's] absence what Allah would have them guard. But those [wives] from whom you fear arrogance - [first] advise them; [then if they persist], forsake them in bed; and [finally], strike them. But if they obey you [once more], seek no means against them. Indeed, Allah is ever Exalted and Grand. ([4:34](https://legacy.quran.com/4/34))

which lead to the conclusion that a wife only must obey a husband who can be in charge for her etc.

Finally marriage is not the only solution Islam provides to avoid zina. So your claim that you need to get married at the age of 16 in order to avoid zina is not strong enough to be rejected or refuted.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you can live your life after marriage well you can otherwise you should do fasting beside obligatory fasts, fast occasionally other days of year except the days fasting prohibited (Eid days). And refrain from obscene material and pornography.

Comment: This actually does not answer the question we are a question and answer site not an internet forum where the answer is more an advice than an answer of the asked question. See [answer].